# PhoneGap - Downloading File From Computer

Tags: cordova

Is there a way to transfer files from a PC to a phone's local storage using PhoneGap?

Answer (score 0):

If you the local PC is running a web browser you should use [FileTransfer.download()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_download). If not then you are stuck with regular means of transferring files. Like "adb push" on Android.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen apps on iPhone that provide a local network ip address + port number on the phone screen that can then be accessed via a browser on a pc to upload a file. Is this possible in PhoneGap?